# Load and use symbols from shared library with ctypes in OCaml toploop

Tags: ocaml, ctypes

I'm trying to use functions from a small self-contained fortran library from OCaml. I can compile the library with `gfortran -shared mvndst.f -o sharedlib`. Invoking `nm sharedlib` shows a list of symbols, e.g. `... T _mvndfn_`.

After reading the ctypes tutorial example https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/wiki/ctypes-tutorial I tried to do something like `let mvndfn = foreign "mvndfn" (ptr double @-> returning float)`. The symbol was not found. Maybe not surprising since I didn't tell it where to look - but I don't know how.

Can this work at all? How to I tell the toploop to look for this shared library? Does it matter that it's Fortran not C? How do I finally compile and link a program if it works in the toploop?

(This is on OS X)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Foreign.foreign` takes an optional argument `?from` that is a value of type `Dl.library` (you can see it [in the docs](http://ocamllabs.github.io/ocaml-ctypes/Foreign.html#VALforeign)). You can get one of those with `Dl.dlopen` (dynamic loading is a complicated topic but you often want `[RTLD_LAZY]`).

Here is an example using `libpng`:

```
# let libpng = Dl.dlopen ~flags:[Dl.RTLD_LAZY] ~filename:"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16";;
val libpng : Dl.library = <abstr>
# open Foreign;;
# open Ctypes_static;;
# let f = foreign ~from:libpng "png_get_libpng_ver" (ptr void @-> returning (ptr char));;
val f : unit Ctypes_static.ptr -> char Ctypes_static.ptr = <fun>
# let p = f Ctypes.null;;
val p : char Ctypes_static.ptr = (char*) 0x7f9d5220e64e
# Ctypes.string_from_ptr ~length:6  p;;
- : string = "1.6.26"
```

Comment: you can find optional arguments in the type of the function by just typing `Foreign.foreign;;` in a toplevel :)